# Como recibir un request de tipo POST via JSON, yo envio desde endpoint de la app y no logro recibir en mi webpage

Tags: php, html, json, post, xmlhttprequest

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y necesito recibir las variables enviadas desde una aplicación en el cuerpo de la solicitud a través de POST por JSON. Ya lo he verificado en una página web (https://hook.ubeac.io/) dedicada a recibir los datos y la página los recibe perfectamente.
Pero no puedo recibir y trabajar con las variables en mi página web, y luego enviarlas a un servidor a través de php. Ya configuré el endpoint (https://miweb.com/beacon.php) para mi web y sin resultados positivos.

Hasta ahora he intentado llegar de muchas maneras, pero ni siquiera puedo decir inicialmente con qué método (código) debería comenzar.
La información que tengo es:
La aplicación es Beacon Scanner, se envían a través de JSON Object en el cuerpo de la solicitud.

Ya he consultado mi URL y no hay desviación.

Los códigos que probé fueron:

```
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode( $info, true);
$beacon1 = print_r($data);

var_dump($info);
echo"<br/>";
var_dump($data);
echo"<br/>";
var_dump($beacon1);
```

Los resultados vistos en la WEB con estos códigos utilizados fueron:
string(0) ""
NULL
bool(true)

Y también intenté recibir como en php directamente, ya que nombré el header del envio como Scanner.

```
$beacon2 = $_REQUEST['Scanner'];
$beacon = $_POST['Scanner'];
if ($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] == "POST")
{ var_dump($beacon2);}
var_dump($beacon2);
echo"<br/>";
var_dump($beacon);
```

respuestas:
NULL

Los datos que deberia recibir son cadenas de unos cuatro de estes:
{
"beacon_type": "ibeacon",
"distance": 1.3859699322772974,
"hashcode": -425134788,
"ibeacon_data": {
"major": "1",
"minor": "22511",
"uuid": "b5b182c7-eab1-4988-aa99-b5c1517008d9"
},
"isBlocked": false,
"last_seen": 1637252214926,
"manufacturer": 76,
"rssi": -75,
"tx_power": -59
}

Espero que, al menos, puedan entender mi duda y contribuir con direcciones. de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo y atencion.

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes de los `var_dump()` en ambos casos? Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar esa información. Para el segundo código, te recomendaría usar `var_dump($_POST);` en lugar de solo una variable.

Comment: Gracias, ya la edité. los resultados: string(0) "" - NULL - bool(true) - NULL. Yo puse lo que me pedio var_dump($_POST); y me retornó: array(0) { }

Comment: ¿Esos resultados corresponden al primer o segundo código?, por favor especifica.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Triby, pero todavia no sé como tener los datos, Yo puse lo que me pedio var_dump($_POST); y del tuyo me retornó: array(0) { }

Comment: Puedes colocar tu codigo funcional aqui https://3v4l.org/ para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ya lo puse, me ahorra un error en la direccion web...Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /in/GOvTr:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /in/GOvTr on line 6... Pero no entiendo bien el error y lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: Trata de colocar tu codigo y danos la url para ayudarte y ver que haces

Comment: la URL es hhttps://3v4l.org/dGPms. es eso? Agradezco mucho su paciencia.

Comment: Estoy un poco frustrado con todo esto, incluso agroa he probado varios caminos y no encuentro respuestas. Ya probé la recepción de datos en "https://hook.ubeac.io/" y en este sitio la información llega correctamente, pero cuando pongo el EndPoint de mi página web no recibe. La aplicación dice en GITHub que necesito tener JSON.google.service en mi aplicación, pero no entiendo cómo puedo configurar dicha acción en mi página web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero valida que están accediendo al `REQUEST` via `POST`

```html
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){
  header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo(json_encode(array("status"=>"failed","error"=>"Metodo no permitido")));
    exit();
};
```

Luego obtienes el contenido

```html
 $postBody = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 
 echo $postBody;
```

Comment: Gracias Wilfredo, al menos ahora me asegura que los datos no están llegando. La duda ahora es que cuando lo envío al endpoint de la página web que yo comenté en la publicación, como por ejemplo (https://hook.ubeac.io/unXD1EQR) se reciben y noto que su URL no tiene la extensión de la página final y cuando la envío en la mía (https://miweb.com/beacon.php), no envía. y no tengo desvios en mi web... el tema es que pongo malo en mi Endpoint...ya probé de muchas maneras y no obtengo suceso

Comment: Pueden haber varios problemas.    1. Tienes un `htaccess` que esta modificando las url,(Si lo tienes edita la pregunta y agrega el código para poder revisarlo).

Comment: 2.Tuiliza un endpoint mas confiable `postman` o si utilizas `vs code` instala el plugin `thunder`

Comment: 3. Puedes hechar un vistazo a este tutorial completo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvKl_-xX1fo&list=PLIbWwxXce3VpvBT_O977da8XECEp-JTJt

Comment: Gracias Wilfredo, del htaccess no tengo y hice pruebas y no apunta desvios en la URL. Voy seguir las recomiendaciones que me indicó y luego comentos se obtuve avanzos.

Comment: Estoy un poco frustrado con todo esto, incluso agroa he probado varios caminos y no encuentro respuestas. Ya probé la recepción de datos en "https://hook.ubeac.io/" y en este sitio la información llega correctamente, pero cuando pongo el EndPoint de mi página web no recibe. La aplicación dice en GITHub que necesito tener JSON.google.service en mi aplicación, pero no entiendo cómo puedo configurar dicha acción en mi página web.